# Retrieving table data from SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve all the `People` in the database table. The table consists of the following columns:

```
ID, FirstName, LastNamre, Age, School
```

In the code below, I am only saving the first 2 values of the table in the list. Where as i want to save all the values in the table to the list.

I have highlighted that part of the code below;

```
i.Add(new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = sql.GetInt32(0).ToString(), 
          Text = sql.GetString(1)  
      });
```

The full code;

```
public List<SelectListItem> getAllPeople()
{
   var i = new List<SelectListItem>();

   try
   {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS", con))
       {
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader sql = com.ExecuteReader();

           while (sql.Read())
           {
               i.Add(new SelectListItem
                         {
                            Value = sql.GetInt32(0).ToString(), 
                            Text = sql.GetString(1)  
                         });
           }
        }
    } 
   ...
```

**UPDATE**

My View class, How to display the value in the view ?

```
@model MyPro.Models.MyPersonModel

....

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
...


@foreach (var item in MyPro.Models.MyPersonModel)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.?????)
        </td>
```

Comment: What is the question??? You posted statement, not a question!

Comment: I am saving only the first, two records in the `i`. I need to store all the table values which are `ID, FirstName, LastNamre, Age, School` in the `variable i`. How can i store the other table fileds in the `variale i`.

Comment: But why you dont want to use `ORMs` like `EF`?

Comment: @Maris Because they are complicated ;-) But then are are things like DataMapper .. or this.

Comment: Please use the google and there is a lot of information about `EF` - EntityFramework. I recommend to look to the way - "code-first" way.

Comment: Also you can read about `lambda-expression`, Linq, `database-first`, `POCO objects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
     public int ID { get;set; }
     public string FirstName { get;set; }
     public string LastNamre { get;set; }
     public int Age { get;set; }
     public string School { get;set; }
}
```

and then use that (instead of `SelectListItem`) when you retrieve the data:

```
public List<Person> getAllPeople()
{
   var people = new List<People>();

   try
   {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS", con))
       {
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader sql = com.ExecuteReader();

           while (sql.Read())
           {
               people.Add(new Person
                          {
                              ID = sql.GetInt32(0), 
                              FirstName = sql.GetString(1),
                              LastName = sql.GetString(2),
                              Age = sql.GetInt32(3) ,
                              School = sql.GetString(4)
                          });
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should i place the Person Class. Is it inside the Model. I have a Model Class that looks exactly the same. Hope you are not refering to the same class ?

Comment: @sharonHwk: yes, it models a `Person` - so I'd put it somewhere in the model

Comment: In your description, you have said to use `SelectListItem `. What does that mean. I have updated my code above.

Comment: @sharonHwk: I said *use `Person` **instead** of `SelectListItem`* ...

Comment: Oh ok, Sorry i didn't read it properly. My question that i wanted to ask was how to read that value from the Views side

Comment: @sharonHwk: that in itself is a whole new, whole different question!

Comment: I am getting an exception `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
` Any idea why this is hapenning ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
i.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Value = sql.GetInt32(0).ToString(), 
    Text = sql.GetString(1) + " " + sql.GetString(2) + " - " + sql.GetString(3) + " - " + sql.GetString(4)
});
```

**UPDATE**

If I were to do this, I'd use ajax so that when the `SelectListItem` changes, I'll get only necessary data via the `People`.`ID` (which is the `SelectListItem`'s Value) instead of getting all the data for all the `People` in the database. Some thing like:

```
$('#SelectListItemId').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "People/GetDetails",
        data: '{ id: this.val() }',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE AFTER ADDING VIEW IN YOUR QUESTION**

Since you did not post your view when I posted my answer and you did not include your `MyPersonModel`, I would assume that this is your `MyPersonModel`?

```
public class MyPersonModel
{
     public int ID { get;set; }
     public string FirstName { get;set; }
     public string LastNamre { get;set; }
     public int Age { get;set; }
     public string School { get;set; }
}
```

Then I believe that your view should be a `IEnumerable<MyPro.Models.MyPersonModel>`

```
@model IEnumerable<MyPro.Models.MyPersonModel>

....

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
...


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastNamre)
        </td>
...
```

And that your retreival code should be like this:

```
public List<MyPersonModel> getAllPeople()
{
   var people = new List<MyPersonModel>();

   try
   {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS", con))
       {
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader sql = com.ExecuteReader();

           while (sql.Read())
           {
               people.Add(new MyPersonModel
                          {
                              ID = sql.GetInt32(0), 
                              FirstName = sql.GetString(1),
                              LastNamre = sql.GetString(2),
                              Age = sql.GetInt32(3) ,
                              School = sql.GetString(4)
                          });
           }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the javascript, your usage of the `SelectListItem` let me to believe that you wanted to display the list of `People` in a Dropdownlist. I was merely suggesting that if that was the case and I were to do it, I'd use javascript to get the other details.

Comment: Ok, and then how am i going to read the values from the View. I have pasted my View code in my post. I want it to be displayed in a grid.

Comment: Please read once more the question? For what you are using the javascript?

Comment: Updated my answer since your original question was not very clear. Please ask better next time.

Comment: I am getting an exception A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll Any idea why this is hapenning ?

Comment: Double check the data types of the incoming data from the database.. Is sql.GetInt32(0) really getting data of type int? How about sql.GetInt32(3)?

Answer (score 1):

Add the class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public Int32 ID {get;set;
     public String FirstName {get;set;}
     public String LastNamre {get;set;}
     public Int32 Age {get;set;}
     public String School {get;set;}
}
```

And modify the selector:

```
           i.Add(new SomeClass
                     {
                        ID = sql.GetInt32(0).ToString(), 
                        FirstName = sql.GetString(1),
                        LastNamre = sql.GetString(2),
                        Age = sql.GetInt32(3),
                        School = sql.GetString(4)
                     });
```

Comment: `SelectListItem` is a .NET standard class - you cannot "override" and redefine it....

Comment: Oh, my bad. Modified the answer

Comment: Should i change the method signature in anyway `public List<SelectListItem> getAllPeople()` ?

Comment: Yes. you have to change it to public List<SomeClass> getAllPeople()

Comment: Also var i = new List<SelectListItem>(); to var i = new List<SomeClass>();

Comment: But, `SomeClass ` just looks the same as my Model class which is also SomeClass. So can i make use of that Model class here instead of creating a new class called `SOmeCLass` ?

Comment: OffCourse, SomeClass = model of the your table.